# Correlation coefficient between normal and half-normal distribution

Tags: correlation, covariance

If X~N(0,1) then let Y=|X|. Y is said to have half-normal distribution.
I know that E(X)=0. Therefore to find Cov(X,Y), I need to find E(XY)=E(X|X|).
I know how to find the distribution of Y. And then I can calculate the mean and variance of Y but I was hoping for a shorter way. Also I don't know how to find E(XY)

Comment: Since $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, $X|X|$ and $-X|-X|=-X|X|$ have the same expectation. But since expectation is linear, their expectations must be negatives of each other: $E(-X|X|)=-E(X|X|)$.  What real numbers equal their own negatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X*|X|)=0$. 
Just express the expectation as an integral and break X into two parts: $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$. And you will get the answer.